# Prove that $f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2+y^4}{|x|+3|y|}$ has a removable discontinuity at $0$ and find its value explicitly.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Prove that $\exists\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
> \begin{align}
> f&\colon \mathbb{R}^2&\to& \mathbb{R}&\\
> &(x,y)&\mapsto&f(x,y)=\cases{\frac{2x^2+y^4}{|x|+3|y|}\;\;\;,(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
> \beta \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\, ,(x,y)=(0,0).}
> \end{align}
> is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't really know where to start, I tried taking the limits (separately) as $x\to0$ and $y\to 0$ getting to the functions $f(x,0)=2|x|$ and $f(0,y)=\frac{1}{3}y^3$ but I don't think this is useful at all.
How could I prove the statement? Any solutions or good hints are more than welcomed.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake, I have corrected the function shown on the question. Thanks.

Comment: In both cases the limit is $0$ as that variable goes to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{2x^2+y^4}{2|x|+3|y|}\le |x|+\dfrac{|y|^3}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider an open set  $x^2+y^2\lt \epsilon^2$ around the origin.  Here $f(x,y)\lt \epsilon$.  Take limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0,y\to 0}f(x,y)=0$.